# Unnecessary @SuppressWarnings("unused") in Java

Tags: java, warnings

I have a function that is called only in debug mode. If I do not add:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
```

I get a warning because the function is never used, in non debug mode.
If I add it a get a warning because for an `Unnecessary @SuppressWarnings("unused")`, in debug mode.

What do you normally do to avoid it?

Comment: Is it really THAT annoying that you want it removed permanently? You should try changing the warning levels in the preferences.

Comment: Maybe out of topic... but can you explain how you check that you are in debug mode ? (i.e. how do you know that you need to call the function or not ?)

Comment: I would live with the warning in debug compilations. That is the simplest way of getting a completely clean non-debug build.

Comment: To me, the fact that your execution path changes when debugging is more of a smell than an unused method warning. Why are you changing method invocations like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the flag which checks for debug mode not statically determined.

```
static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.getBoolean("debug");
```

or

```
static final boolean DEBUG = LOGGER.isDebugEnabled();
```

or

```
static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
```

This will stop the static analysis being about to determine whether you have debug enabled or not.

Comment: I like the solution DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");

Comment: Thinking about it that would mean that I would slow down the execution for the release

Comment: It won't make a significant difference. `static final` values can be inlined at runtime just as efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and make the method protected and that should remove the warning. The other option is to change the preferences.